# @FirestoreQuery Not returning list of documents in Collection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm using FirebaseFirestoreSwift and Swift5.5 on iOS15+

I have this query:

```
@FirestoreQuery(
    collectionPath: "/Users/" + Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid + "/Pages/"
) var pages2: [PageItem]
```

And I'm trying to get the following:

[image: The structure is: Users/{userId}/Pages/{pageId}/{key/value pairs}]

The structure is: `/Users/{userId}/Pages/{pageId}/{key/value pairs}`

I even confirmed from Firestore that the path was matching with its own.

This is from the console: `/Users/JuzWOzAf54a7oFlOlb09dhAuOjI3/Pages/LZQAmbb18tYtz8ypkd8p`

and this is what my string concatenation produces: `/Users/JuzWOzAf54a7oFlOlb09dhAuOjI3/Pages/`

So I *should* be getting the Page `LZQAmbb18tYtz8ypkd8p` and 3 others in the response, but thus far it is empty. Am I checking too early?

I am printing it like so:

```
.onAppear {
    print(pages2)
}
```

On a view in the same file.

I don't even think it's a problem with printing it too soon, since it's meant to update in real-time.

But just incase it never showed since it was `onAppear`,and could have been received after, I added the following:

```
List {
    ForEach(pages2) { page2 in
        Text(page2.name)
    }
}
```

And still, it receives nothing.

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong, I've researched and all I can find is a few resources, but they all seem to be doing the same thing, however, mine is simply not working, or I might be confused.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

**Edit**
This is the official SDK file whose methods I'm using:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firestore%2FSwift%2FSource%2FPropertyWrapper%2FFirestoreQuery.swift

I am doing exactly as they propose.

Comment: This may be an asynchronous issue so you may be checking too early. However, there's not enough code to know for sure. Can you provide a more complete code example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: A few quick notes: (1) Please don't access the current user like this. Force unwrapping might crash your app if `currentUser` is `nil`. Instead, set up an `AuthStateListener`. (2) All Firebase APIs are asynchronous, so the data will very likely arrive *after* `onAppear` is executed. See https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firebase-async-calls-swift/ for more details about this. (3) Your security rules might prevent the user from being able to read the collection. Update your security rules and try again. (4) As Jay suggested, please provide more context so we can help better.

Comment: @PeterFriese I’m happy to fetch like the docs state, using documents, but do I have to call the tasks onAppear?

Comment: @MeersE.Chahine - as mentioned before, we'd need more details to answered *why* your code doesn't seem to work. Did you check Security Rules? The Firebase SDK contains a complete working example for how to use the `@FirestoreQuery` property wrapper - see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Example/FirestoreSample/FirestoreSample/Views/FavouriteFruitsView.swift (there are some other examples in this project, too - check them out).